# Does $T\setminus S$ make sense even if $S$ is not a subset of $T$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Very simple question.  I have a set $S$ which contains some elements of set $T$ but $S\nsubseteq T$.  Is it proper for me to define

$$ X=T\setminus S $$

even though $S$ is not a subset of $T$?  My goal is to define $X$ as the set of elements in $T$ which are not in $S$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, since $T\setminus S$ *means* $\{x\in T\mid x\notin S\}$. This definition doesn't assume that $S\subset T$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's fine.

Note that this would be equal to $T\setminus(S\cap T)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is fine. For any two subsets of another set (for example $T\cup S$),
$$T\setminus S=T\cap S^c$$
There is no requirement that $S$ be a subset of $T$.